# Outlook 2010 need to show replied/forwarded time

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to know or get the data of the sent time/replied time on my emails? Can someone show it?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any problem here: just look at message date and note "You replied to this message on ..." tip on the preview pane (right below the header):

[image]

Screenshot shows Outlook 2013, but the same applies for Outlook 2010.

Comment: Actually, that's my problem, as I have to get these information for around 500 e-mails, if possible, I want it to have as an additional column on my outlook or run a tool that will provide that information easier. Thanks!